# PyQt5: Keyboard shortcuts w/ QAction

Tags: python, pyqt, keyboard-shortcuts, python-3.4, pyqt5

How do I implement keyboard shortcuts (to run a function) in PyQt5? I see I'm supposed `QAction` in one way or another, but I can't put the two and two together, and all examples don't seem to work with PyQt5 but instead PyQt4.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use `QShortcut` and `QKeySequence` classes like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeySequence
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QShortcut, QLabel, QApplication, QHBoxLayout

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.label = QLabel("Try Ctrl+O", self)
        self.shortcut = QShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+O"), self)
        self.shortcut.activated.connect(self.on_open)

        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.resize(150, 100)
        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_open(self):
        print("Opening!")

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = Window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 8):

Also possible simply to write

```
my_action.setShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+Shift+A"))
```

If you already have the action defined elsewhere.

---

An example of defining an action looks like this:

```
from aqt import mw

def testFunction():
    showInfo("Hello action!")

my_action = QAction("test", mw)
my_action.triggered.connect(testFunction)
my_action.setShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+Shift+A"))
```

Comment: Hello may I ask what is `my_action` or what object is it? I think your answer is great!

Comment: Could you please add an example code... your answer is very much helpful to others :)

Answer (score 1):

It can be more simple and more powerful, depending on your needs:

```
QShortcut( 'Shift+Ins', tree_view ).activated.connect( lambda : tree_view.add_row( 'next sibling' ) )
```

... passes the string 'next sibling' as parameter to the method `tree_view.add_row`.

Also check out the "Standard Shortcuts" section in [QKeySequence](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/api/qtgui/qkeysequence.html?highlight=qkeysequence#QKeySequence): probably usually best to stick with the platform-specific conventions (and not override them inadvertently...) unless there's a good reason to do otherwise.