# QShortcut & QKeySequence with Shift+Return in a QPlainTextEdit element

Tags: python, pyqt5, keyboard-shortcuts, qkeysequence, qshortcut

I have an element, `editorBox` which is of the PyQt5 element type `QPlainTextEdit`. My target goal is to call a function when the hotkey `Shift + Return` is pressed, and my goal with this function is that it will also insert text into the editorBox element (this isn't the part I'm stressed about, it's fairly easy to do with the `.insertPlainText()` method).

I've done searching, and the closest result I could find was to use `QShortcut` & `QKeySequence` paired together like so:

```
# Initialize the QShortcut class
self.keybindShiftEnter = QShortcut(QKeySequence("Shift+Return"), self)
# Connect the shortcut event to a lambda which executes my function
self.keybindShiftEnter.activated.connect(lambda: self.editorBox.insertPlainText("my text to insert"))
```

For clarification, I have tried using other characters in the `QKeySequence` constructor, such as `Ctrl+b`, and I've had success with it. Oddly enough, only the combination `Shift+Return` doesn't work for me.

I've analyzed a problem with it in relation to my bug. Some of the posts I've viewed:

- [This is for triggering a button, not a QPlainTextEdit.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46055411/pyqt-trigger-a-button-with-ctrlenter)
- [Best thing I've tried, almost worked up until I tried Shift+Return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25989610/pyqt5-keyboard-shortcuts-w-qaction)
- [Any solution with keyPressEvent wouldn't work, because keys other than Shift+Enter wouldn't be typed into the editorBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35033116/in-pyqt-how-to-print-ctrlkey-in-qlineedit-when-pressed-ctrl-anykey)

Comment: Implementing keyPressEvent *is* the solution, you just have to call the base class implementation whenever the key press does not match shift-enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own problem:

```
# ... editorBox Initialization code ...
self.editorBox.installEventFilter(self)

# Within App class
def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
    if obj is self.editorBox and event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress:
        if isKeyPressed("return") and isKeyPressed("shift"):
            self.editorBox.insertPlainText("my text to insert")
            return True
    return super(App, self).eventFilter(obj, event)
```

What I'm doing here is setting a filter function- basically, every time a key is pressed (any key, including space/backspace/etc) it will call the `eventFilter` function. The first `if` statement makes sure that the filter will only pass through if it is a key stroke (not entirely sure if this part is necessary, I don't think clicks trigger the function). Afterwards, I utilize the `isKeyPressed` function (a renamed version of the `keyboard` module's `is_pressed` function) to detect if the current key is held down. With the `and` operator, I can use this to make keybind combos.